# Saving the output of a for loop to a data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, netcdf

I'm trying to apply a function to a netcdf data frame per row. Here's the reading part of the script.

```
library(ncdf4)
library(car)
library(forecast)
ncname <- "plus1"             
ncfname <- paste(ncname,".nc", sep="")
dname <- "precip"
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
lon <- ncvar_get(ncin,"lon")
nlon <- dim(lon)
lat <- ncvar_get(ncin,"lat",verbose=F)
nlat <- dim(lat)
t <- ncvar_get(ncin,"time")
tunits <- ncatt_get(ncin,"time","units")
nt <- dim(t)
tmp_array <- ncvar_get(ncin,dname)
nc_close(ncin)
tmp_vec_long <- as.vector(tmp_array)
tmp_mat <- matrix(tmp_vec_long, nrow=nlon*nlat, ncol=nt)
lonlat <- as.matrix(expand.grid(lon,lat))
tmp_df02 <- data.frame(cbind(lonlat,tmp_mat))
tmp_df03<-na.omit(tmp_df02)

tmp_df03$lamb<-apply(tmp_df02[3:365],1,function(x)BoxCox.lambda(x,method="loglik",lower=-2,upper=2))
```

I want to use the values in the column tmp_df03$lamb and apply for each row of the data frame. For example (x should be the name of the data frame):

```
trans<-yjPower(x,tmp_df03$lamb,jacobian.adjusted=TRUE)
```

If I put this in a for loop:

```
d<-matrix(ncol=363,nrow=899)
for (i in 1:899){
trans[i]<-yjPower(as.numeric(tmp_df03[i,][3:365]),tmp_df03$lamb[i],jacobian.adjusted=TRUE)
d<-rbind(d,trans) 
}
```

I encountered the following warning message.

Warning messages:

```
1: In trans[i] <- yjPower(as.numeric(tmp_df03[i, ][3:365]), tmp_df03$lamb[i],  :
```

number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Question:

1. How can I combine the output of the for loop and create a new data frame of the results?
2. Can anyone suggest how any method of solving this?

I'll appreciate any help. 
Many thanks,

Comment: @joel.wilson.Sorry I'm really new in R. For each row, there is a different value of lambda. I dont know how to implement this using the apply function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using sapply() - I'm not much aware of yjPower() , so just giving you a hint!

```
vec <- sapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) yjPower(x[i,], tmp_df03$lamb[i], jacobian.adjusted = TRUE))
```

So above code will give a vector : to make this as a data.frame, use as.data.frame() on this vector.

If you want to join this to "x" then use cbind(x, as.data.frame(vec))

Comment: Many thanks for your help. tried yjPower(as.numeric(tmp_df03[i,]), tmp_df03$lamb[i] and this works fine. Whenever I apply the yjPower without the as.numeric it gives me an error. I dont know why.

Comment: Either `seq_along` or `1:nrow(x)`- no need in both

Comment: @joel.wilson. Is there a way to preserve the original format of the data frame while using the sapply function?The output of data.frame(vec) is 899 columns rather than 363 from the original.

Comment: Oops..a simple transpose will do the trick. t(name of data frame).